# Backbone.js comparator not working on certain browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, internet-explorer, backbone.js, marionette

I am using Backbone.js and Marionette.js for my webapp and in that webapp I am using comparators to sort my Backbone collections.

Those comparators seem to be working just fine on Google Chrome and Firefox (all versions tested), however they don't seem to be working on iOS 11 (Safari and my Cordova app) or on Internet Explorer 11. My Backbone collections remain unsorted after applying the comparator and calling `.sort`.

Anyone have any idea why the backbone `comparator`/`sort` method doesn't work on these browsers?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: maybe they need a repaint to be done of the collection items

Comment: Since I posted this question I noticed that IE is actually sorting my collection, just backwards. If I use the negative of my ordinal for the comparator, everything looks fine in IE, but then its backwards in Chrome :(

Comment: Please provide implementation of the comparator